# Using an HTTP PROXY - Python

Tags: python, http, proxy, urllib2

I familiar with the fact that I should set the HTTP_RPOXY environment variable to the proxy address.

Generally urllib works fine, the problem is dealing with urllib2.

```
>>> urllib2.urlopen("http://www.google.com").read()
```

returns

```
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it>
```

or

```
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed>
```

---

#### Extra info:

#### urllib.urlopen(....) works fine! It is just urllib2 that is playing tricks...

I tried @Fenikso answer but I'm getting this error now:

```
URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the 
connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established
connection failed because connected host has failed to respond>
```

---

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post actual whole sample code which gives you the error?

Comment: @Fenikso: this `urllib2.urlopen("http://www.google.com").read()`

Comment: So you have the proxy server set in HTTP_PROXY environment variable? Are you sure that server accepts the connection?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can do it even without the HTTP_PROXY environment variable. Try this sample:

```
import urllib2

proxy_support = urllib2.ProxyHandler({"http":"http://61.233.25.166:80"})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_support)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

html = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.google.com").read()
print html
```

In your case it really seems that the proxy server is refusing the connection.

---

Something more to try:

```
import urllib2

#proxy = "61.233.25.166:80"
proxy = "YOUR_PROXY_GOES_HERE"

proxies = {"http":"http://%s" % proxy}
url = "http://www.google.com/search?q=test"
headers={'User-agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'}

proxy_support = urllib2.ProxyHandler(proxies)
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_support, urllib2.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=1))
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

req = urllib2.Request(url, None, headers)
html = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
print html
```

---

**Edit 2014:**
This seems to be a popular question / answer. However today I would use third party [`requests`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests) module instead.

For one request just do:

```
import requests

r = requests.get("http://www.google.com", 
                 proxies={"http": "http://61.233.25.166:80"})
print(r.text)
```

For multiple requests use `Session` object so you do not have to add `proxies` parameter in all your requests:

```
import requests

s = requests.Session()
s.proxies = {"http": "http://61.233.25.166:80"}

r = s.get("http://www.google.com")
print(r.text)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! :) Now I'm getting `URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond>`... urllib works perfectly though.

Comment: @RadiantHex - Works fine on my system. Do you have any proxy you have to use for internet access?

Comment: @RadiantHex - What is also the type of proxy you use?

Comment: @Fenikso: I do have to use an http proxy for internet access, and it is the same I use for all my software to get internet access. It is the same proxy I have set within the HTTP_PROXY variable.

Comment: @RadiantHex - Try setting another user-agent and switch debug mode on. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @RadiantHex - So was it the proxy refusing connection because of user-agent?

Comment: I thought this was working for me, but tried putting random information passed in with proxies, and data was still retrieved each time (as long as https was used)

Comment: Is there a proxy for FTP?

Comment: @Fenikso, what is `"http": "http://61.233.25.166:80"` line `proxies` argument? Is it gonna be my IP address?

Comment: @voo_doo it is address and port of the proxy you want to use.

Comment: did you ip bind the proxy or is the proxy allowing your accesss?

Answer (score 19):

I recommend you just use the requests module.

It is much easier than the built in http clients:
http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html

Sample usage:

```
r = requests.get('http://www.thepage.com', proxies={"http":"http://myproxy:3129"})
thedata = r.content
```

Comment: How do you set the timeout?

Comment: Wonderful. This works with both https and http, whereas urllib only works with http for me with python3.

Comment: I thought this was working for me, but tried putting random proxy information, and data was still retrieved each time (as long as https was used)

Answer (score 6):

Just wanted to mention, that you also may have to set the **`https_proxy`** OS environment variable in case https URLs need to be accessed.
In my case it was not obvious to me and I tried for hours to discover this.

My use case: Win 7, jython-standalone-2.5.3.jar, setuptools installation via ez_setup.py

Answer (score 4):

Python 3:

```
import urllib.request

htmlsource = urllib.request.FancyURLopener({"http":"http://127.0.0.1:8080"}).open(url).read().decode("utf-8")
```

Comment: from the TraceBack: DeprecationWarning: FancyURLopener style of invoking requests is deprecated. Use newer urlopen functions/methods.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this on jython client.
The server was only talking TLS and the client using SSL context.

`javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance("SSL")`

Once the client was to TLS, things started working.