# python urllib connect the server return socket error, error code is 10061

Tags: python, sockets, urllib

I have 500 clients use the program, the program use `python 2.7.12` + `pyqt`, the OS is `windows XP`, But now a computer has a error. The error is that when use `urllib.urlopen`, it returns socket error, error code is `10061`.
But, i.e., the server IP is `192.168.1.12`, the computer can open the web page use `IE browser` with http://192.168.1.12, and use the cmd: `telnet 192.168.1.12 80`, it's fine.
The computer's Windows firewall is disabled, and the antivirus software is closed. But when use `urllib.urlopen('http://192.168.1.12')`, it always returns socket error `10061`. The other 500 clients don't have this issue, only this one. And I checked the IE browser settings, it's not set proxy. Anybody can help me ? I need your help, thanks all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python urllib.request.urlopen() returning error 10061?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9586951/python-urllib-request-urlopen-returning-error-10061)

Comment: Maybe, I'll try it. Thanks

Comment: I checked the IE browser settings, it's not set Proxy.

Comment: You already tried telnet, so what is the error message, when you try `socket().connect(('192.168.1.12', 80))` directly from Python?

Comment: @dhke It shows: File "socket.pyc", line 575, in create_connection  \n IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 10061]

Comment: @JianhuaZhu Sounds awfully like a "personal firewall" issue, but you already wrote that firewall and antivirus are off. Does `socket.getaddrinfo('192.168.1.12', 80)` return anything strange on the problematic host?

Comment: @dhke But now I can't debug it, because the custom's computer no python and I no permission install python on it, and I'll try it on my computer later.

Comment: @JianhuaZhu erm? The system is built using Python and the target machine does not have Python on it?

Comment: @dhke yes, the target computer OS is windows xp, it's no python on it, and because secrecy, I can't use it debug.

Comment: @dhke And, the program used on this computer more than 1 year, it can't connect the server from 2016-08-18. The server has no any change.

Comment: @dhke I solved the problem. Like this urllib.urlopen("http://192.168.1.12", proxies={})

Comment: @JianhuaZhu So somebody has setup a broken proxy configuration on that machine ...