# Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time

Tags: python, http, python-2.7

```
def check_web_server(host, port, path):
        h = httplib.HTTPConnection(host, port)
        h.request('GET',path)
        resp = h.getresponse()
        print 'HTTP Response:'
        print '   status =', resp.status
        print '   reason =', resp.reason
        print 'HTTP Headers:'
        for hdr in resp.getheaders():
                print '  %s: %s' % hdr
```

I called this function like this `check_web_server('www.python.org',80,'/')`
but it gave me this error
`error: [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond`

You can see the code clearly here
http://pastebin.com/V9KpGkvw

I have searched here in Stackoverflow but I didnt find any relevant questions
sorry I am new to site ,if I Did anything wrong.

Comment: Must be your setup, works for me. Try `ping www.python.org` and `telnet www.python.org 80` in your shell to see if python.org actually is reachable from your development setup.

Comment: it is reachable using ping www.python.org

Comment: Works fine here, must be related to some problem with your configuration.

Comment: @Madhu13 Did you try the `telnet www.python.org 80`? What was the result? (If you get a connection, try typing `GET /` followed by Enter and see if you get a response.)

Comment: @zigg with the telnet I am getting error "Could not open connection to the host, on port 80 : connection failed"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As `ping` works, but `telnet`to port `80` does not, the HTTP port `80` is closed on your machine. I assume that your browser's HTTP connection goes through a proxy (as browsing works, how else would you read stackoverflow?). 
You need to add some code to your python program, that handles the proxy, like described here:

[Using an HTTP PROXY - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620263/using-an-http-proxy-python)

Comment: This is probably the right answer, but I think the more accurate diagnosis is not that port 80 is necessarily "closed on [OP's] machine", which implies a local service is not listening, but rather that port 80 access to www.python.org is blocked, be it by firewall (either local or remote) or some other network condition.

Comment: You are right, but that's what I also meant. "closed" should be a synonym for "not accessible", regardless wheather blocked locally or by firewall