# Python error when import Twisted

Tags: python, twisted

I am running on Windows 8.1. I have installed Python 2.7.2, Zope interface 4.1.1 and Twisted 64bits.

When I use twisted, I get a really awkard error.
I have always used twisted and never got this error.

I get this after writing `from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol`

> ```
> socket.error: [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected pa
> rty did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection f
> ailed because connected host has failed to respond
> ```

Comment: Please copy and paste the text of the error into your question... and the relevant section of code

Comment: Probably the ports are closed?

Comment: Its looking like @keiv.fly could be on to something here.. [Related post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14143198/errno-10060-a-connection-attempt-failed-because-the-connected-party-did-not-pro).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is saying the server you are trying to connect to did not respond. You are either not correcting to the right server, or the server is not set up to reply as you are wanting it to. Another possibility is that you do not have the appropriate ports open to make the connection.