# Hey, I get this error when I run this code in jupyter notebook. Any ideas why? TimeoutError: [WinError 10060]

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

**Error:**

> TimeoutError:
> [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

---

The code:

```
# Install Tensorflow Object Detection 
if os.name=='posix':  
    !apt-get install protobuf-compiler
    !cd Tensorflow/models/research && protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=. && cp object_detection/packages/tf2/setup.py . && python -m pip install . 
    
if os.name=='nt':
    url="https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/download/v3.15.6/protoc-3.15.6-win64.zip"
    wget.download(url)
    !move protoc-3.15.6-win64.zip {paths['PROTOC_PATH']}
    !cd {paths['PROTOC_PATH']} && tar -xf protoc-3.15.6-win64.zip
    os.environ['PATH'] += os.pathsep + os.path.abspath(os.path.join(paths['PROTOC_PATH'], 'bin'))   
    !cd Tensorflow/models/research && protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=. && copy object_detection\\packages\\tf2\\setup.py setup.py && python setup.py build && python setup.py install
    !cd Tensorflow/models/research/slim && pip install -e .
```

Comment: There is similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14143198/errno-10060-a-connection-attempt-failed-because-the-connected-party-did-not-pro) error resolved by community which can be helpful.