# Scraping data from multiple links on a webpage

Tags: python, r, web-scraping, scrapy

I am attempting to gather data on the cost of living index for all the cities in Texas from the website below: `http://www.city-data.com/city/Texas.html`

What would be the easiest way to scrape the data from the webpage? I have tried using a Chrome extension called Web Scraper, but was not successful. I am thinking it might work better with R using the XML package or trying Scrapy out. I looked up both approaches but am somewhat lost, and was looking for some direction. Any input would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [BeautifulSoup4](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) (bs4) to parse and read HTML-Data.
Please have a look at this example:

```
In [4]: from urllib2 import urlopen

In [5]: citylinkpage = urlopen("http://www.city-data.com/city/Texas.html")

In [7]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

In [8]: soup = BS(citylinkpage)

In [9]: allImportantLinks = soup.select('table.cityTAB td.ph a')

In [10]: print allImportantLinks[:10]
[<a href='javascript:l("Abbott");'>Abbott</a>, <a href='javascript:l("Abernathy");'>Abernathy</a>, <a href="Abilene-Texas.html">Abilene, TX</a>, <a href="Addison-Texas.html">Addison, TX</a>, <a href="Alamo-Heights-Texas.html">Alamo Heights</a>, <a href='javascript:l("Albany");'>Albany, TX</a>, <a href="Alice-Texas.html">Alice</a>, <a href="Allen-Texas.html">Allen, TX</a>, <a href='javascript:l("Alma");'>Alma, TX</a>, <a href="Alpine-Texas.html">Alpine, TX</a>]

In [14]: allCityUrls = ["http://www.city-data.com/city/"+a.get('href') for a in allImportantLinks if not a.get('href').startswith('javascript:')]

In [15]: allCityUrls
Out[15]: 
['http://www.city-data.com/city/Abilene-Texas.html',
 'http://www.city-data.com/city/Addison-Texas.html',
 'http://www.city-data.com/city/Alamo-Heights-Texas.html',
 'http://www.city-data.com/city/Alice-Texas.html',
 'http://www.city-data.com/city/Allen-Texas.html',
 'http://www.city-data.com/city/Alpine-Texas.html',
 'http://www.city-data.com/city/Amarillo-Texas.html',
...
```

Because the Page of each city seems to be bad HTML (especially around this index) it seems better to search the page via regular expressions (using built-in `re`-module)

```
cityPageAdress = "http://www.city-data.com/city/Abilene-Texas.html"
pageSourceCode = urlopen(cityPageAdress).read()
import re
expr = re.compile(r"cost of living index in .*?:</b>\s*(\d+(\.\d+)?)\s*<b>")
print expr.findall(pageSourceCode)[0][0]
Out: 83.5
```

Comment: What does the #pageSourceCode = ... refer to in the second bit of the code? I was not able to run that chunk of code.

Comment: Is there a way to prevent the website from crashing when I run the code? I tried running the code with the url list partitioned in sets of 400, but it still crashes. Any ideas? error: urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed becau
se the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or estab
lished connection failed because connected host has failed to respond>

Comment: @user11235813: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620263/using-an-http-proxy-python

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have one more question. Is it possible to extract the county name of the city using a regular expression?

Comment: This looks like a case for beatifulsoup4: I look for every link that starts with "/county", take the first one and take its text: `soup.select('a[href^=/county]')[0].getText()`

Answer (score 0):

Give scrapy a try. [Check out my blog post on recursive scraping](http://philipcodings.com/post/recursively-crawling-a-website-with-python-and-scrapy)