# Errno 10060 using pandas.get_csv in Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, pandas, proxy

I'm using eclipse behind a proxy server, and I have the correct proxy information setup in the Preferences->General->Network Connections

HTTP
HTTPS

I know this is working because I can use the Help->Check for Updates, or Help->Install New Software.

However when I try and do some basic python code to get data from Quandl, I keep getting this weird error:

```
QUANDL_API_URL = 'https://www.quandl.com/api/v1/'
url = QUANDL_API_URL + 'datasets/{}.csv?'.format("FRED/GDP")
```

in this case url =

```
https://www.quandl.com/api/v1/datasets/FRED/GDP.csv?
```

I know this is correct, because you can get to that URL in chrome and download the csv file, and then I am reading it in python using:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv(url, index_col=1)
```

and I am getting the following stack trace:

```
URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond>
```

Is there something weird I need to do in Eclipse to get this to function?  Disclosure using another IDE like Canopy, this works fine, without errors.  Any clue?

Thanks -

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Windows, this is could be a configuration issue (environmental variable HTTP_PROXY may be a good place to start).

As a work-around, I would consider using something like urllib2 to get the CSV and passing that into read_csv instead of passing in the URL directly.

This answer seems appropriate for you:
[Using an HTTP PROXY - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620263/using-an-http-proxy-python)