# Biopython: url open error for qblast

Tags: biopython

I am trying a basic Biopython example from an online course. However, I am unable to query the NCBIWWW database to align a query sequence. The program fails with a URL error.

My code is as follows:

```
from Bio.Blast import NCBIWWW, NCBIXML

fasta_string = "TGGGCCTCATATTTATCCTATATACCATGTTCGTATGGTGGCGCGATGTTCTACGTGAATCCACGTTCGAAGGACATCATACCAAAGTCGTACAATTAGGACCTCGATATGGTTTTATTCTGTTTATCGTATCGGAGGTTATGTTCTTTTTTGCTCTTTTTCGGGCTTCTTCTCATTCTTCTTTGGCACCTACGGTAGAG"

h = NCBIWWW.qblast("blastn", "nt", fasta_string)
```

However, this returns the following error:

```
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known>
```

Do I need to configure Biopython before I use it? I think I am using the correct parameters to the blast function.

Comment: it works fine for me ...... do server connection have **proxy** ?

Comment: hmmmmm... what do you mean by "proxy server connection have proxy"? I'm afraid, I do not quite follow.

Comment: may be, you must add proxy configuration [using-an-http-proxy-python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620263/using-an-http-proxy-python) ....

Comment: `import urllib2; urllib2.urlopen("http://www.google.com").read()` is It working ?

Comment: That bit works. I get the webpage HTML...

Comment: ok It isn't proxy problem, do you made many requests to NCBI ? ..... they deny service after many many many requests

Comment: No, it was the first time I tried it today as I just learnt about Biopython. It also does not say anything about connection timing out.... just the error message that I posted... The thing is now I tried the same code from my university machine and it worked...