# How to read JSON from URL in Python?

Tags: python, json, urllib2, urllib

I am trying to use Python to get a JSON file from the Web. If I open the URL in my browser (Mozilla or Chromium) I do see the JSON. But when I do the following with the Python:

```
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
data = json.loads(response.read())
```

I get an error message that tells me the following (after translation in English): Errno 10060, a connection troughs an error, since the server after a certain time period did not react, or the connection was erroneous, or the host did not react.

**ADDED**

It looks like there are many people who faced the described problem. There are also some answers to the similar (or the same) question. For example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620263/using-an-http-proxy-python) we can see the following solution:

```
import requests

r = requests.get("http://www.google.com", proxies={"http": "http://61.233.25.166:80"})
print(r.text)
```

It is already a step forward for me (I think that it is very likely that the proxy is the reason of the problem). However, I still did not get it done since I do not know URL of my proxy and I probably will need user name and password. Howe can I find them? How did it happen that my browsers have them I do not?

**ADDED 2**

I think I am now one step further. I have used this site to find out what my proxy is: http://www.whatismyproxy.com/

Then I have used the following code:

```
proxies = {'http':'my_proxy.blabla.com/'}
r = requests.get(url, proxies = proxies)
print r
```

As a result I get

```
<Response [404]>
```

Looks not so good, but at least I think that my proxy is correct, because when I randomly change the address of the proxy I get another error:

```
Cannot connect to proxy
```

So, I can connect to proxy but something is not found.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: URLError: <urlopen error \[Errno 10060\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15820739/python-urlerror-urlopen-error-errno-10060)

Comment: You have to check the routes to find your proxy. On windows, you can control your network settings. If you need to pass a username and password, you can passthem directly in the URL in proxies dict: http://user:password@61.233.25.166:80.

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be something wrong, when you're trying to get the json from the online source(URL). Just to make things clear, here is a small code snippet

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

try:
    # For Python 3+
    from urllib.request import urlopen
except ImportError:
    # For Python 2
    from urllib2 import urlopen

import json

def get_jsonparsed_data(url):
    response = urlopen(url)
    data = str(response.read())
    return json.loads(data)
```

If you still get a connection error, You can try a couple of steps:

1. Try to urlopen() a random site from the Interpreter (Interactive Mode). If you are able to grab the source code you're good. If not check internet conditions or try the request module. [Check here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests/)
2. Check and see if the json in the URL is in the correct syntax. For sample json syntax check [here](http://json.org/example.html)
3. Try the simplejson module.

Edit 1:
if you want to access websites using a system wide proxy you will have to use a proxy handler to use loopback(local host) to connect to that proxy.. A sample code is shown below.

```
proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler({
    'http': '127.0.0.1',
    'https': '127.0.0.1'
})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
# this way you can send both http and https request using proxies
urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com')
urllib2.urlopen('https://www.google.com')
```

I have not not worked a lot with ProxyHandler. I just know the theory and code. I am sure there are better ways to access websites through proxies; One which does not involve installing the opener everytime you run the program. But hopefully it will point you in the right direction.

Comment: My problems happen at step 1 (so, it is not about parsing JSON). I have tried to open different URLs and it does not work. It s not about internet connections since I do see these URLs in my browsers. I think it is about proxy. Somehow my browser requests can go through it and Python is not.

Comment: If your computer uses a proxy setting ehn you will have to install a proxy handler to access websites using the system wide proxy settings. I will edit the answer above to include the code.

Comment: The code above will route your program to your localhost(127.0.0.1) from where it will again be routed to your proxy (system set) and then to the requested website.