# Trouble connecting to the internet with Python using urllib2

Tags: python, networking, proxy, urllib2

So I have a pretty basic python script that I'm trying to use to retrieve information from a website. I know this code is correct because it runs just fine on my home PC, but not on my company's PC.

```
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen('https://www.website.com/')
```

Every time I run the script, it just hangs for a couple minutes, until it eventually throws the following error:

> IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

After searching other posts, I found that similar problems were proxy related issues. I checked my PC's network settings to see if I could find a proxy address and found that my company set up a automatic configuration script. I followed the link and downloaded the script, and I think I found which proxy I should use. I edited my code according to another post on how to include a proxy. See below:

```
import urllib2
proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': 'proxy1.companywebsite.com:80'})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
response = urllib2.urlopen('https://www.website.com/')
```

When I run this, it still hangs and throws an error:

> URLError: urlopen error [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the   connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond>

If anybody has any ideas on why this isn't working, I'd greatly appreciate it. I've spent hours trying to figure this out.

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620263/using-an-http-proxy-python .

Comment: You have written urllib2.open instead of urllib2.urlopen but i guess it is not the real problem is it?

Comment: @PyProgrammer yes that was a mistake in me copying the code. definitely not the cause

Comment: Yeah, just making sure .... it would throw different error

Comment: I would use requests module to handle those things so u can try.... http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/  usage with proxy is:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287628/proxies-with-python-requests-module