# A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time or connected host has failed to respond 99

Tags: python, request, urllib2, urllib3

I've tried a lot way to read the content or extract background HTML from other website using Python 3.5.

I'm familiar with Using an HTTP PROXY, I develop my project on Windows Server 2008 r2, and it's the policy of the company.

Below is my simple code to be able to request connection to the other website.

```
 import requests
 r = requests.get("https://stackoverflow.com", 
             proxies={"http": "http://proxy.com:900"})
 print(r.text)
```

> Its work when I change the url to google urls as below

```
r = requests.get("https://www.google.com", 
             proxies={"http": "http://proxy.com:900"})
```

When i use url from another website.

Then, I got this error on the output.

```
  C:\Python35\python.exe C:/Users/mwirzonw/PycharmProjects/untitled/test.py
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 141, in 
 _new_conn
 (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
 File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 83, 
 in create_connection
 raise err
 File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 73, 
 in create_connection
 sock.connect(sa)
 TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the 
 connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or 
 established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 600, 
 in urlopen
 chunked=chunked)
 File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 345, 
 in _make_request
 self._validate_conn(conn)
 File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 844, 
 in 
 _validate_conn
 conn.connect()
 File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 284, in 
 connect
 conn = self._new_conn()
 File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 150, in 
 _new_conn
 self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
 urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: 
 <urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000000003694390>: 
 Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt 
 failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period 
 of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed 
 to respond

 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 440, in 
 send
 timeout=timeout
 File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 649, 
 in urlopen
 _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
 File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 388, in 
 increment
 raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
 urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: 
 HTTPSConnectionPool(host='stackoverflow.com', port=443): Max retries 
 exceeded with url: / (Caused by 
 NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 
 0x0000000003694390>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] 
 A 
 connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly 
 respond 
 after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected 
 host has failed to respond',))

 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/mwirzonw/PycharmProjects/untitled/test.py", line 4, in 
  <module>
  proxies={"http": "http://proxy.com:9"})
 File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 72, in get
   return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 58, in request
   return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 502, in 
  request
  resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 612, in 
  send
  r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 504, in 
  send
   raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
   requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: 
   HTTPSConnectionPool(host='stackoverflow.com', port=443): Max retries 
   exceeded with url: / (Caused by 
   NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 
   0x0000000003694390>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 
   10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not 
   properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed 
   because connected host has failed to respond',))

   Process finished with exit code 1
```

I really need help from who read this post. Because I'm new to python and I've tried a lot of methods.

> I've tried using urllib2, urllib3, using request based on this post-[Using an HTTP PROXY - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620263/using-an-http-proxy-python)

But still get the same output.

Thank you....

Comment: what is the url that gives the error? where is the code for calling that request? we can't reproduce the error without seeing that

Comment: Is it possible that the proxy is blocking the request?  Have you tried it from the browser first?

Comment: On the top of my question, I already posted my coding. its requests from the stack URL and bypass by using the proxy and read all the content of the URL @OferSadan

Comment: Yaa, but I have included the proxy to bypass from blocking. It's weird because when comes to Google URL it successful to show the Output. @JohnScattergood