# Python TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed

Tags: python, smtplib

I am trying to make a python program that checks to see if the cost has changed or not for a website. However, every time I run the code it comes up with this python error below and then I can not access the site on any devices in the house for a period of time without is saying 'This site can’t be reached the site took too long to respond.'
Even though it doesn't load for me the website is still working

Code below

```
try:
from urllib.request import urlopen
import smtplib
import time
except ImportError:
# Fall back to Python 2's urllib2
from urllib2 import urlopen

ufo = urlopen("https://www.tinydeal.com/mystery-floating-ufo-flying-saucer-
frisbee-magic-trick-toy-p-157394.html")
time.sleep(5)

knife = urlopen("https://www.tinydeal.com/3-in-1-paring-knife-slicer-triple-
fruit-vegetable-cooking-tool-p-163606.html")
time.sleep(5)

mosquito = urlopen("https://www.tinydeal.com/2-in-1-mosquito-killer-lamp-
led-night-light-romantic-sleeping-lamp-p-160265.html")
time.sleep(5)

lenovocase = urlopen("https://www.tinydeal.com/soft-silicone-frosted-back-
case-for-lenovo-vibe-shot-z90-7-p-159210.html")
time.sleep(5)

cereal = urlopen("https://www.tinydeal.com/cereal-double-dispenser-machine-
breakfast-food-storage-container-p-167155.html")
time.sleep(5)

onion = urlopen("https://www.tinydeal.com/onion-goggles-cutting-onion-
glasses-bbq-eye-protective-anti-spicy-no-tears-p-167156.html")

print('Have they changed price?\n')
print ('Mystery Floating UFO Flying Saucer Frisbee Magic Trick')
if ufo == '£1.07':
print ('yes')
else:
print ('no')

print ('3-in-1 knife')
if knife == '£2.31':
print ('yes')
else:
print ('no')

print ('mosquito')
if mosquito == '£3.85':
print ('yes')
else:
print ('no')

print ('lenovo case')
if lenovocase == '£0.69':
print ('yes')
else:
print ('no')

print ('cereal')
if  cereal == '£13.88':
print ('yes')
else:
print ('no')

print ('onion goggles')
if  onion == '£2.31':
print ('yes')
else:
print ('no')
```

The error I get is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1183, in do_open
h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers)
File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 1137, in request
self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 1182, in _send_request
self.endheaders(body)
File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 1133, in endheaders
self._send_output(message_body)
File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 963, in _send_output
self.send(msg)
File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 898, in send
self.connect()
File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 1279, in connect
super().connect()
File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 871, in connect
self.timeout, self.source_address)
File "C:\Python34\lib\socket.py", line 516, in create_connection
raise err
File "C:\Python34\lib\socket.py", line 507, in create_connection
sock.connect(sa)
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the 
connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or 
established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Ollie\Desktop\g2.py", line 12, in <module>
knife = urlopen("https://www.tinydeal.com/3-in-1-paring-knife-slicer-triple-
fruit-vegetable-cooking-tool-p-163606.html")
File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 161, in urlopen
return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 464, in open
response = self._open(req, data)
File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 482, in _open
'_open', req)
File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 442, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1226, in https_open
context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1185, in do_open
raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [WinError 10060] A connection attempt 
failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period 
of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed 
to respond>Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1183, in do_open
h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers)
File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 1137, in request
self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 1182, in _send_request
self.endheaders(body)
File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 1133, in endheaders
self._send_output(message_body)
File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 963, in _send_output
self.send(msg)
File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 898, in send
self.connect()
File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 1279, in connect
super().connect()
File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 871, in connect
self.timeout, self.source_address)
File "C:\Python34\lib\socket.py", line 516, in create_connection
raise err
File "C:\Python34\lib\socket.py", line 507, in create_connection
sock.connect(sa)
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the 
connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or 
established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Ollie\Desktop\g2.py", line 12, in <module>
knife = urlopen("https://www.tinydeal.com/3-in-1-paring-knife-slicer-triple-
fruit-vegetable-cooking-tool-p-163606.html")
File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 161, in urlopen
return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 464, in open
response = self._open(req, data)
File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 482, in _open
'_open', req)
File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 442, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1226, in https_open
context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1185, in do_open
raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [WinError 10060] A connection attempt 
failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period 
of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed 
to respond>Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1183, in do_open
h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers)
File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 1137, in request
self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 1182, in _send_request
self.endheaders(body)
File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 1133, in endheaders
self._send_output(message_body)
File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 963, in _send_output
self.send(msg)
File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 898, in send
self.connect()
File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 1279, in connect
super().connect()
File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 871, in connect
self.timeout, self.source_address)
File "C:\Python34\lib\socket.py", line 516, in create_connection
raise err
File "C:\Python34\lib\socket.py", line 507, in create_connection
sock.connect(sa)
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the 
connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or 
established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Ollie\Desktop\g2.py", line 12, in <module>
knife = urlopen("https://www.tinydeal.com/3-in-1-paring-knife-slicer-triple-
fruit-vegetable-cooking-tool-p-163606.html")
File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 161, in urlopen
return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 464, in open
response = self._open(req, data)
File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 482, in _open
'_open', req)
File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 442, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1226, in https_open
context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1185, in do_open
raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [WinError 10060] A connection attempt 
failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period 
of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed 
to respond>
```

Comment: If you are in a VPN or using a proxy then this question has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620263/using-an-http-proxy-python