# urllib.request.urlretrieve leads to an urlopen error [WinError 10060]

Tags: python-3.x, urllib, urlretrieve

I try to download a tgz file from an url. If I use the link and copy it to Firefox, a download-as dialog occures and I can download the data.

If I use this code, I get an `urlopen error`:

```
urllib.request.urlretrieve(HOUSING_URL, "C:/HomeC/data.tgz")
```

Does anybody know, what I'm doing wrong? Again: The link, stored in HOUSING_URL is correct and working in a browser. There are also no mistakes by typing it, as I copy the path directly from the "Watch window" in Visual Studio

Comment: Can you show us the traceback?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any proxies setup?
You could try this -

```
image = urllib.URLopener(proxies={})
image.retrieve(HOUSING_URL, "C:/HomeC/data.tgz")
```

You can check these too 
[Using an HTTP PROXY - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620263/using-an-http-proxy-python)

Answer (score 0):

you can add these code before retrieve data

```
# set proxy
proxy = urllib.request.ProxyHandler({"https":"http://your proxy IP:port"})
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(proxy)
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)

urllib.request.retrieve(housing_url, tgz_path)
...
```