# How to proxy for OpenWeatherMap API

Tags: python, api, proxy, openweathermap

i have a program and i want to show the current weather information in the corner. The code works at my own computer but at my work notebook i cant establish connection and i get this error:

> requests.exceptions.ProxyError:
> HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.openweathermap.org', port=443): Max
> retries exceeded with url:
> /data/2.5/weather%5Bhttps://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather%5D?APPID=abc123
> d88&q=Frankfurt&units=metric (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to
> proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection
> object at 0x000002563074FB48>: Failed to establish a new connection:
> [WinError 10060]

I found this as a solution and i sounds promising:
[Using an HTTP Proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620263/using-an-http-proxy-python)

Unforutnately i dont get it how i need to implement it because i dont have knowledge about the internet settings of the company. Something similar to this:

```
response = requests.get(url, params=params, proxies={"http": "12.34.56.78:1234", "https": "12.34.56.78:1234"})
```

what i do know is that i need to set this in PyCharm's Terminal to use pip install, and it seems related:

> set HTTP_PROXY=12.34.56.78:1234
> set HTTPS_PROXY=12.34.56.78:1234

I dont understand much about network settings but with that it works. Would i have to do this for the program as well? The port of the error message (443) is not matching to the port i enter above (1234).

Can you help me here? Would be much apreciated! :-)

Comment: you don't have to set proxy in terminal - it should work with `get( proxies={...})` but usually problem is free proxy servers are outdated and they don't work. Only paid proxy servers work correctly. Or you may try to use `Tor Network` as proxy server.

Comment: in `requests` you may have to use `http://` or `https://` in addresses - `proxies={"http": "http://12.34.56.78:1234", "https": "https://12.34.56.78:1234"}`

Answer (score 0):

I solved it:

i defined this globally:

```
proxies = {'http':'http://12.34.45.67:1234','https':'http://12.34.45.67:1234'}
```

And made my request like this:

```
response = requests.get(url, params=params, proxies=proxies)
```

I had some typos in the code before, which didnt help also ...

Comment: it doesn't matter that you defined it globally - but now you used adresses with prefix `http://` and it could change everything.

Comment: That's true. I m happy anyway :)